# why I can parse the string with JSON.parse

Tags: json, request

I make a request for some data, and the sever send me back a json data, here is my code

```
var request = require('request');
var Iconv = require('iconv-lite');
var Q = require('q');
var gbk = require('gbk');

var limitUpUrl = 'http://vip.stock.finance.sina.com.cn/quotes_service/api/json_v2.php/Market_Center.getHQNodeData?page=1&num=1&sort=changepercent&asc=0&node=hs_a&symbol=&_s_r_a=setlen';

function RequestURL (url) {
  var defered = Q.defer();
  request({
      url: url,
      encoding: null
    }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        return defered.reject(error);
      }
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var str = Iconv.decode(body, 'GBK')
        defered.resolve(str);
      }
    })
  return defered.promise;
}

 RequestURL(limitUpUrl).then(function (res) {
  console.log(res);
  console.log(JSON.parse(res))
 }, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
 })
```

the string looks like normal, but when I run it in chrome develop tools, it throw an error. But I can't fix it.

Comment: What does `console.log(res);` output?

Comment: What error does it throw?